# How to use latest Lightning design styles in component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a lightning component as below on Opportunity standard lightning page.

**Example.cmp:**

```
<aura:component 
    implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" 
    access="GLOBAL">
    <c:svgComponent 
        xlinkHref="/resource/SLDS212/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#product" 
        class="slds-icon" />
</aura:component>
```

**svgComponent.cmp:**

```
<aura:component >
  <aura:attribute name="class" type="String"/>
  <aura:attribute name="xlinkHref" type="String"/>
  <aura:attribute name="ariaHidden" type="String" default="true"/>
</aura:component>
```

Also, I have a static resource uploaded with name `SLDS212`.

For every release, I go to [Downloads - Lightning Design Systems](http://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/downloads/), download new file and upload to static resource and update my components.

Is there a better way to do this, instead of downloading the styles sheet for every release and uploading?

Please note that there is no `<aura:application>` involved here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cascading Style Sheets "cascade", meaning that since LEX uses SLDS, you don't need to import the styles a second time. Simply assume that they exist and work correctly. When possible, use [standard components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components) with standard documented values; if SLDS changes, those components will take on the new styles as well.

---

For example, svgComponent has been deprecated, and it is expected that you will use `lightning:icon` or one of the other variants, such as `lightning:buttonIcon` if you need an icon button:

```
<lightning:icon iconName="standard:product" />
```

Comment: So what should I pass for `xlinkHref` attribute in my example?

Comment: @javanoob In your specific case, use the standard `lightning:icon` component, such as `<lightning:icon iconName="standard:product" />`.

Comment: @javanoob Also, as an aside, Salesforce specifically recommends that you do not use svgIcon, but instead use the standard component.